# Installing Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to set up Chrome Remote Desktop on Elementary. I downloaded the chrome remote desktop `.deb` package from their website, installed it through `Eddy`, but I can't launch that app and complete the setup as it doesn't appear anywhere. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For me, you need before **install Google Chrome first**

```
# Download
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

# Install
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

and after you need install **Chrome Remote Desktop**

```
# Download
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb

# Install
$ sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb

# Install dependencies
$ sudo apt install -f
```

You can also install **Google Chrome Desktop** in Chrome Web Store

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp

After activate the service **chrome-remote-desktop.service**

```
$ systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop
```

you will also need to configure the service

https://remotedesktop.google.com/access

Comment: I did exactly that, and on https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/ I get "Set up another device for remote access" screen which probably means it thinks this computer is already connected. But I didn't finalize the process (didn't set password anywhere). Also seems like the Chrome Web Store app is obsolete, it only redirects to the website now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I fixed it by just manually creating a ~/.chrome-remote-desktop-sessions config file with my default gnome session preferences in there (See step 3 of google's support page here: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1649523?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)